# Latest CEDET version can't load semantic packages

Tags: emacs, cedet

I am having problems loading some of the semantic packages that Alex Ott recommends in [his well-known guide to CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) when using the recent versions of CEDET.

My previous setting worked with no problem in Emacs 24.2.1, but I just **upgraded** to the latest version of CEDET in Bazaar, and Emacs run into problems when attempting to load the `semantic-*` packages. Following Alex's guide, I had the following commands in my `.emacs` file:

```
(require 'semantic-ia)
(require 'semantic-gcc)
(require 'semanticdb)
```

and Emacs now complains saying that it's unable to load those modules.

Same thing when running the command:

```
(global-semantic-tag-folding-mode 1)
```

Where did this functionality go in the latest versions of CEDET? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: I added note to my article that describe which versions of CEDET it covers, and which config to use for newer versions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After CEDET 1.1, it started to use the same activation scheme as CEDET in GNU Emacs, but article still talks about versions of CEDET before 1.1. I plan to update article when I'll find time. In the meantime, you can take my [actual CEDET config](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el) - it uses new activation scheme.

Comment: Thanks Alex! I think this also fixed [a problem I was having parsing header files with older versions of semantic](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el). By the way, is there a way to customize the face of the `stickyfunc-mode` header line?

Comment: I hadn't found this right now in the source code, so it's better to ask in the mailing list