# Emacs CEDET: Unresolved paths in header files, but resolved in .cpp files

Tags: emacs, cedet

I have set up my include paths in `ede-cpp-roo-project` following [Alex's guide to CEDET](http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html) and the documentation that comes with CEDET. Many paths are resolved correctly. However, I have noticed that some of by system headers are unresolved in an `.h` file even **though they are resolved** in a `.cpp` file.

I am using the latest version of CEDET on Bazaar and Emacs 24.2.1. and I have defined the following project:

```
(ede-cpp-root-project "One"
                :name "One Project"
                :file "/path/to/file/in/the/project"
                :include-path '("/")
                :system-include-path '("path/1/"
                       "/path/2"                       
                       "/path/3"
                       )
                :spp-table '(("isUnix" . "")
                             ("BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK" . "")))
```

In one of my `.cpp` files, the headers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
```

are resolved, but they are not resolved in the associated `.h` file. I have tried reparsing the `.h` file multiple times ( <kbd>C-c , ,</kbd> ), restarting Emacs, etc. with no results.

In case it matters, I noticed that my `.cpp` file is opened in `c++-mode` while the `.h` file is loaded in `c-mode`. However, if I try to change the mode of any of these files, all the includes become unresolved (and reparsing with   <kbd>C-c , ,</kbd>  doesn't help).

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading CEDET to the [latest version in Bazaar](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/bzr-repo.shtml) fixed it.

See this other thread: [Latest CEDET version can't load semantic packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946084/latest-cedet-version-cant-load-semantic-packages) for information on how to set up CEDET with the new version (in particular, [Alex Ott's configuration file at GitHub](https://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-cedet.el) for CEDET).